# How to Validate DateTime 4 Controls in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datetime, telerik

I'm having a hard time to validate for RadDateTimePickers in Javascript
I have an update button which trigger a function in JS that validates date and time for 4 controls.
The controls are: Clock In, Start Break , End Break, Clock Out.

My logic is:

- List item
  1). Clock In cannot be after start break. end break, clock out.
- List item
  2). Start Break cannot be before clock in, after end break, after clock out.
- List item
  3). End Break cannot be before clock in, before start break, after clock out.
- List item
  4). Clock out cannot be before clock in,before start break,before end break.

JS function:

```js
  function ValidateTransaction() {
        var ClockIn = $find("<%=rdtpClockIn.ClientID %>");
        var ClockInDate = ClockIn.get_selectedDate();
        var ClockOut = $find("<%=rdtpClockOut.ClientID %>");
        var ClockOutDate = ClockOut.get_selectedDate();

        var StartBreak = $find("<%=rdtpStartBreak.ClientID %>");
        var StartBreakDate = StartBreak.get_selectedDate();
        var EndBreak = $find("<%=rdtpEndBreak.ClientID %>");
        var EndBreakDate = EndBreak.get_selectedDate();

        // Validation for ClockIn.
        if (ClockInDate != null) {
            // ClockIn cannot be after startBreak.
            if (StartBreakDate != null) {
                if ((StartBreakDate - ClockInDate) < 0) {
                    radalert("Clock In DateTime cannot be after Start Break DateTime.<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 440, 170, "Case Global Alert");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // ClockIn cannot be after EndBreak.
            if (EndBreakDate != null) {
                if ((EndBreakDate - ClockInDate) < 0) {
                    radalert("Clock In DateTime cannot be after End Break DateTime.<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 440, 170, "Case Global Alert");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // ClockIn cannot be after ClockOut.
            if (ClockOutDate != null) {
                if ((ClockOutDate - ClockInDate) < 0) {
                    radalert("Clock In DateTime cannot be after Clock Out DateTime.<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 440, 170, "Case Global Alert");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } // End Clock In Validation.

         // ============================== //
        // Validation for StartBreak.
        if (StartBreakDate != null) {
            // Start Break Cannot be before Clock In.
            if (ClockInDate != null) {
                if ((ClockInDate - StartBreakDate) < 0) {
                    radalert("Start Break DateTime cannot be before Clock In DateTime.<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 440, 170, "Case Global Alert");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // Start Break cannot be after End Break.
            if (EndBreakDate != null) {
                if ((EndBreakDate - StartBreakDate) < 0) {
                    radalert("Start Break DateTime cannot be after End Break DateTime.<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 440, 170, "Case Global Alert");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // Start Break cannot be after Clock Out.
            if (ClockOutDate != null) {
                if ((ClockOutDate - StartBreakDate) < 0) {
                    radalert("Start Break DateTime cannot be after Clock Out DateTime.<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 440, 170, "Case Global Alert");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } // Start Break Validation.

        // ============================== //
        // Validation for EndBreak.
        if (EndBreakDate != null) {
            // End Break Cannot be before Clock In.
            if (ClockInDate != null) {
                if ((ClockInDate - EndBreakDate) < 0) {
                    radalert("End Break DateTime cannot be before Clock In DateTime.<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 440, 170, "Case Global Alert");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // End Break Cannot be before Start Break.
            if (StartBreakDate != null) {
                if ((StartBreakDate - EndBreakDate) < 0) {
                    radalert("End Break DateTime cannot be before Start Break DateTime.<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 440, 170, "Case Global Alert");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // Start Break cannot be after Clock Out.
            if (ClockOutDate != null) {
                if ((ClockOutDate - EndBreakDate) < 0) {
                    radalert("End Break DateTime cannot be after Clock Out DateTime.<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 440, 170, "Case Global Alert");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } // End Break Validation.
    }
```

```html
  <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtpClockIn" runat="server" DbSelectedDate='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ClockInDateTime") %>' Width="192px">
                             <Calendar ID="calanderClockIn" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="True">
                                <SpecialDays>
                                    <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" Date="" ItemStyle-BackColor="lightblue"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                                 </SpecialDays>
                             </Calendar> 
                            <DateInput ID="diClockIn" ToolTip="ClockIn Date input" runat="server"/>   
                       </telerik:RadDateTimePicker
    
    
    
       <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtpStartBreak" runat="server" DbSelectedDate='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.StartBreakDateTime") %>' Width="192px">
                        <Calendar ID="calanderStartBreak" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="True">
                                <SpecialDays>
                                    <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" Date="" ItemStyle-BackColor="lightblue"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                                 </SpecialDays>
                             </Calendar> 
                            <DateInput ID="diStartBreak" ToolTip="Start Break Date input" runat="server"/>   
                        </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
    
    
       <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtpEndBreak" runat="server" DbSelectedDate='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EndBreakDateTime") %>' Width="192px">
                         <Calendar ID="calanderEndBreak" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="True">
                            <SpecialDays>
                              <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" Date="" ItemStyle-BackColor="lightblue"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                            </SpecialDays>
                          </Calendar> 
                         <DateInput ID="diEndBreak" ToolTip="End Break Date input" runat="server"/>   
                        </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
    
      <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtpClockOut" runat="server" DbSelectedDate='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ClockOutDateTime") %>' Width="192px">
                          <Calendar ID="calanderClockOut" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="True">
                            <SpecialDays>
                              <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" Date="" ItemStyle-BackColor="lightblue"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                            </SpecialDays>
                          </Calendar> 
                         <DateInput ID="diClockOut" ToolTip="Clock ut Date input" runat="server"/>  
                        </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
    
    
    
       <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" OnClientClick="ValidateTransaction(); return false;" Visible='<%# Not (TypeOf DataItem Is Telerik.Web.UI.GridInsertionObject) %>'></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to ease up things. Here is some code to give you direction:

```
function ValidateTransaction() {
    var ClockIn = $find("<%=rdtpClockIn.ClientID %>");  
    var ClockOut = $find("<%=rdtpClockOut.ClientID %>");
    var StartBreak = $find("<%=rdtpStartBreak.ClientID %>");
    var EndBreak = $find("<%=rdtpEndBreak.ClientID %>");

    var ClockOutDate = ClockOut.get_selectedDate();
    var ClockInDate = ClockIn.get_selectedDate();   
    var StartBreakDate = StartBreak.get_selectedDate(); 
    var EndBreakDate = EndBreak.get_selectedDate();

    var mClockOut=moment(ClockOutDate), 
        mClockIn=moment(ClockInDate),
        mStartBreak=moment(StartBreakDate),
        mEndBreak=moment(EndBreakDate);

    //clock in should be befor start break
    if(!mClockIn.isBefore(mStartBreak){
        //handle invalid date
    }

    if(!mStartBreak.isBetween(mClockIn, mEndBreak)){
        //start break is not valid
    }

    if(!mEndBreak.isBetween(mStartBreak, mClockOut)){
        //end date is invalid
    }

    /*SIMILLARLY YOU CAN VALIDATE OTHER INTERVALS*/
}
```